# How can I quickly boost Lily Rank?

Tags: neptunia-v

Much to my horror I have found that to get several trophies you need to basically max all possible Lily Rank pairs in the game. After 1.5 playthroughs my ranks are around 3-4 on average, being optimistic.

How can I most quickly build Lily Rank? Just fight a lot with Game Discs with the + Lily Rank boost? Do I have to finish battles or is there some better way to farm by running away from the same enemy or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lily Rank only increases by fighting battles when paired up. I don't recall the exact number of battles, but it's somewhere along the lines of like 50-60 battles with the pair setup to increase one rank normally. It's... a really long process unassisted.

The only way to increase this is to use the Lily Rank+ bonus, from an Idea Chip or from a Godly Game combination. This reduces the number of battles that must be fought significantly. With a level 5 Lily Rank+, it takes only about 10 battles to increase the Lily Rank. Level 3 would take 30 battles per rank up. Most importantly, **the front line character has to be the one with the chip effect equipped**. Putting it on someone in the back lines won't help at all.

I believe that finishing the battle is necessary, but when the Colosseum opens, battle count is extremely simple. The Dogoo fight is in a perfect position for several character's AoE attacks to clear it instantly, and since it's the Colosseum you don't have to wait for respawning. Now, admittedly, I haven't actually tried this for Lily Rank boosting, but if anything would speed it up faster than just fighting on the field as you go through the game, this would be it.